# Angular - How to format 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 as null in Angular

Tags: angular

In Angular 14, I am using date pipe to format the date coming from the database.

```
<td>{{mDetail?.processedDate | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy' || 'N/A'}}</td>
```

From SQL Server, null date is returned as `0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000`, so when it gets to the Angular date pipe format, it is displayed as `01-Jan-0001`.

How do I format `0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000` to be `N/A` as shown in the code above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own pipe that takes in a date and a format string and formats it according to your needs. (e.g. return 'N/A' if the date is too long ago)

for a start you can look into the angular date pipe here: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/common/src/pipes/date_pipe.ts

The actual code is only a few lines and if you adjust the first one to this:

```
if (value == null || value === '' || value !== value || value === '0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000') return 'N/A';
```

it should work